# Unable to get contents of clipboard (Java)

Tags: java, clipboard

I am running the following code:

```
String clipBoardText;

public String getAllTextOfPage() {
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(null);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(
            stringSelection, null);

    Robot r = null;
    try {
        r = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        System.out.print(ie.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);

    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

        try {
            clipBoardText = (String)clipboard.getContents(null).getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            System.out.println(clipBoardText);
        }
        catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    return clipBoardText;
}
```

The console output is as follows:

```
null

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But when I paste the contents of the clipboard into notepad, it has the contents I'm looking for. So it seems to be a problem with how I am retrieving the clipboard contents.

Comment: Have you tried `clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)`? I'm not sure, but there could be something about `getContents(null)` that isn't working.

Comment: Tried using that, same results. Pasting the actual string I'm looking for into my ide shows that there are some unexpected tokens, like quotes and \n. Could this be the cause of my problem?